# SQL Learning case statements with aggregation

Tags: sql, case, aggregation

I am trying to tie budget totals to sales using fiscal year and fiscal period since the budget table does not have the date column that the sales table has. I am trying to aggregate the budget table to sum some budget numbers by fiscal year and period.  Here is what I have.

```
SELECT 
    BRANCH_ID, BRANCH_NAME, FISCAL_YEAR, FISCAL_PERIOD, sum(GL_BUDGET) AS I_NEED_TO_FILTER_THIS
FROM
    connection.subsection.FACT_BRANCH_BUDGET
WHERE
    FISCAL_YEAR = '2022'
GROUP BY 
    BRANCH_ID, BRANCH_NAME, FISCAL_YEAR, FISCAL_PERIOD
Order by 
    BRANCH_ID, BRANCH_NAME, FISCAL_YEAR, FISCAL_PERIOD
```

This gives me the summations for each branch, fiscal year and fiscal period but I am having difficulty with the CASE statement.  I need to filter for only certain codes under GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER but keep getting errors.

Thanks.

Comment: `sum(case when GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER  in (1, 2, 14, 55) then GL_BUDGET else 0 end)`.

Comment: BTW, that's a case _expression_.

Comment: Also, you can also put the GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER  condition in the WHERE clause, with the consequence that 0 budget rows will not be shown at all.